connecting javascript code to html file/getting it to appear in html
I'm currently working on a project that involves an NBA api that utilizes promises and async functions. In this case, I'm not sure why my javascript function (updatetable) is not showing up in the  section when called.
Here's this section I have in HTML:
<div class="second-row-hidden">
            <h1>Predicted Roster </h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="stat-names">
                        <th id="player">Player</th>
                        <th id="player-country">Country</th>
                        <th id="player-gp">GP</th>
                        <th id="player-mp">MP</th>
                        <th id="player-ppg">PPG</th>
                        <th id="player-rpg">RPG</th>
                        <th id="player-apg">APG</th>
                        <th id="player-bpm">BPM</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="player-data">
                    </tr>
                        <td colspan="8">Loading...</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

Here is the Javascript file:
async function filterByConditions() {
    const finalPlayers = [];
    const playerStats = await fetchPlayerStats();

    for (let i = 0; i < playerStats.length; i++) {
        const player = playerStats[i];
        if (player.Country === 'USA' && player.GP >= 60 && player.MIN >= 30) {
            finalPlayers.push(player);
        }
    }
    return finalPlayers.slice(0,12);
}

async function updateTable() {
    const finalPlayers = await filterByConditions();
    const tableBody = document.getElementById('player-data');
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';

    finalPlayers.forEach(player => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        Object.keys(player).forEach(key => {
            const cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = player[key];
            row.appendChild(cell);
        });
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    });
}

updateTable();

There is more async functions that build upon each other prior to filterbyConditions(). At the end with filterbyConditions() it is supposed to return an array of dictionaries with the keys listed in the html section ex: {Player: Stephen Curry, Country: USA, GP: 65...etc...} that hopefully displays each element into the table cells in html. Any help is appreciated!
I tried implementing the script straight into the html file and leaving it in an external file. Nothing changed. I've tried almost everything to get the html connected to the javascript and I'm not sure what the issue is.

As questioned in staging ground by
JaromandaX :  What is the value of playerStats - if that is an empty array, then that is the problem. use console.log to determine the content of playerStats

Please click [edit] and then [<>] to make a [mcve] - mock the object

There is  an error in your current HTML: <tbody id="player-data"></tr> You are trying to close a tr element which you never opened.

Also make sure that there is only one element with that given id in your page. Maybe your code is updating another instance that precedes the one you're observing, and that may be hidden. Anyway, without you providing a minimal reproducible example it's all guess work.

That being said, it's easy to test if the error is in the fetch part. Just return an array with fake data from the filterByConditions() function, and see if your fake data is placed in the table. If it is, then the error is in your fetch code. If it isn't, then the error is in your DOM manipulation code.
